# Subtracting 2 Dates from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Dates which I pull out from a database. One being a Start Time and One being an End Time. I am wanting to find the difference between the 2 dates and then display the time taken between the 2 on the same page.

I have seen this code on other answers but I am new to this so not sure where to place it and then display it on a page.

```
var ExecutionSeconds = execution.End.Subtract(execution.Start).TotalSeconds;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well have you already fetched the two values? It feels like your problem doesn't really have much to do with subtracting one date from another, but more "How do I get data onto the page..."

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is without given us more context.  It seems you've already figured out how to do the actual date math; so what is it that you're asking?  Without some more context, it won't really be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Have you got anything that can help solve your problem so far?

Comment: Yes that would be correct, also, not sure where to place this code. I would like to know how the get the result of the date math onto the view

Comment: It seems to me that your code, being a business logic calculation, should go in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using ViewBag.

### Controller

```
ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds = (execution.End - execution.Start).TotalSeconds;
```

### View

```
@ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The first Thing is that you Need a `DbContext` in your conroller to get `execution` from you database. Then you can execute your code line to determine the time span in seconds.

The second part is to give this value to your view. For example by passing it to the View-method as the model:

```
    //fetch your data and calculate ExecutionSeconds...
    return View(ExecutionSeconds);
}
```

Inside the View you can access your model by declaring the `@model` element and accessing the Model property:

```
@model Int32

@* other HTML code you need *@

<span>The timespan is @Model seconds long</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have read only property on the model

```
public int ExecutionDiff{
    get{
        return this.End.Subtract(this.execution.Start).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Or put calculated value to the ViewData or ViewBag and take value from there

Answer (score 1):

one way to have the below function which gives you the difference in days.If you want to check difference in js change the function appropiately.

```
public int DayDiffrenceInt(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        var a = (date2.Date - date1.Date).Days;
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query contains `StartDate` and `EndDate`, Then you can subtract each row this way:

```
var dateQuery = dateTimeQuery.Select(p => p.StartDateTime - p.EndDateTime).ToList();
```

Then you can assign that query in a ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.DateTimes = dateQuery;
```

So inside your view you can easily show it:

```
foreach (var dateTime in ViewBag.DateTimes)
{
    <li>@dateTime.TotalSeconds</li>
}
```